# Displaying info window when tapped marker in google maps iOS sdk while implementing mapView:didTapMarker: delegate method implemented

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

Ok it is a long title. I am having trouble when i use google maps iOS sdk. I want to show an info window about a marker which user tapped. According the documentation if snippet and title properties of GMSMarker are both selected info window will be shown when user tapped that marker. But I also implement mapView:didTapMarker: method from GMSMapViewDelegate protocol. If I comment out that method info window is visible otherwise info window is not visible. So how can I show info window when that method implemented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement `GMSMapViewDelegate`'s `mapView:didTapMarker:` method and make it return `false`.

**Swift Implementation:**

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: return false make the marker to the center. What if I dont want to center the tapped marker

Answer (score 0):

For those interested - Swift 5.5 ios 15

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    // return false - show marker info, return true - not show
    return false
}
```