# Programmatically display a GMSMarker's info window

Tags: swift, google-maps

*I know there is already a question similar to this on SO ([Displaying info window when tapped marker in google maps iOS sdk while implementing mapView:didTapMarker: delegate method implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564172/displaying-info-window-when-tapped-marker-in-google-maps-ios-sdk-while-implement)) but the answer does not apply in my case.*

In my `mapView(didTap:)` delegate method, it **has to** `return true` because I programmatically determine the camera position when a marker is tapped. If I `return true` like the answer in the above question says, the map is automatically centered on the selected marker, which I do not want. Since I `return true`, tapping a marker does not display the marker's information window, which I still want to occur, so is there a way for me to do that programmatically?

*I don't think the code in my  `mapView(didTap:)` delegate method is necessary for answering this question, but if anyone needs it, let me know. (Keep in mind that my question question refers to the delegate method for when a marker is tapped, not the delegate method for when an info window is tapped, `mapView(didTapInfoWindowOf:)`)*

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Looking through the Google Maps Documentation, I found out that there is a method for what I am looking for in JavaScript called `showInfoWindow()` that you call on the marker who's info window you want to show ([this is the link to the documentation I'm talking about](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows)). So does anyone know a Swift 3 alternative to this method?

**Edit:**

If I `return false` in the delegate method, the camera instantly moves to the marker's location for a split second, and then pans over to the location I programmatically tell it to move to. This technically works, but it is ugly and not fluent, so I still need a way to programmatically show the marker's information window while the delegate method returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going on google's issue tracker and [submitting a post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64315159), I found out that `mapView.selectedMarker() = marker` does not actually have any connection to the `mapView(didTap:)` delegate method, so returning `true` in the delegate method has *no impact on the* `selectedMarker()` *method's functionality*.

As a result I can just add `mapView.selectedMarker() = marker` in the delegate method after customizing the location I want to animate the mapView to and before returning `true`, which causes the marker's info window to pop up without messing with the camera position.